# mysql_real_escape_string - access denied, depending on user who executes script?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

My setup: Ubuntu LAMP, application built w/ zend framework

My Problem: I have a few php scripts that I trigger via cron - daily email reports, rrd data capture etc.. I launch them via a cronjob like 'php -f scriptname.php'.
When I test the scripts from the commandline, logged in as myself, everything works fine. However, when the same script executes as root (via cron OR sudo) it fails with the following errors.

Warning: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Warning: `mysql_real_escape_string`(): A link to the server could not be established ...

I've done some research and I'm fairly sure that Im establishing a connection to mysql ahead of time, although the process is a bit obfuscated because Im working with the zend framework- Bootstrap class calls zend_db which calls registry class for the db credentials. and so on.

I've discovered one workaround: 'sudo -u myusername php -f scriptname.php'  but I'd really like to know what Im doing wrong here..

TIA!

Comment: It looks like it's using the current user to generate the mysql login credentials, rather than some configured values.  Do you have a 'root' user setup for the mysql database?

Comment: @krdluzni: You don't have a choice.  root is the first account created when you install a MySQL server.

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate: That root account should never be used to access mysql from an app, so I'm assuming the OP was using an account specifically for the application, but that Zend somehow picked up the 'root' username because of the sudo call. Similar to the last part of Question Mark's response.

Comment: Yes, there is a default root account in mysql. I only use it in phpmyadmin to manage things. My app has it's own mysql user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time guys.  Through trial and error I have determined that the error is related to my Zend Framework implementation.  My bootstrap, db initalization, registry.. who knows.

While I love working with the ZF, simple issues like this turn into huge time vampires.  All Im looking for is a mysql_connect() somewhere!  I'll update when I find something.

Much Thanks..

Comment: Apparently Zend framework recommends it's own $db->quote() method, which will taylor quoting and escaping to whatever db type you use. portable, yes.. annoying, yes!  thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
Warning: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

This is the message you get when you login to mysql server with the wrong username and password, or you log in from a location you are not allowed. Check that root can log in from the host 'localhost' and that it has sufficient permissions for your database and the mysql database.

```
'sudo -u myusername php -f scriptname.php'
```

Maybe Zend is taking your sysem level user id and expecting to log into mysql with that? can you check or override the credentials that zend is using to connect to mysql?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies.. I have three updates:

1) The full error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  

2) There are many other queries in the script that work, only mysql_real_escape_string() does not. I am not passing a db connector parameter to mysql_escape_string becuase I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that the connection was already created

3) My system username is 'todd'.  There is no mysql user 'todd' so the script must be pulling valid mysql credentials at some point?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string must have a mysql resource passed in as well as the string your escaping.  "using password: NO" makes me think (more) that it is trying a last ditch attempt at a connection and defaulting to root.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also appear if there is no database connection.